# Why does the KJV translate Acts 5:24 the way it does?

Tags: acts, translation-philosophy, kjv, priestly

KJV Acts 5 : 24

> Now when the ***high priest*** and the captain of the temple and the ***chief priests*** heard these things, they doubted of them whereunto this would grow.

Acts 5:24 ESV:

> Now when the captain of the temple and the ***chief priests*** heard these words, they were greatly perplexed about them, wondering what this would come to.
> NIV:On hearing this report, the captain of the temple guard and the chief priests were at a loss, wondering what this might lead to.

Acts 5:24 AMP

> :Now when the military leader of the temple area and the ***chief priests*** heard these facts, they were much perplexed and thoroughly at a loss about them, wondering into what this might grow

Acts 5:24 NIV:

> On hearing this report, the captain of the temple guard and the ***chief priests*** were at a loss, wondering what this might lead to.

It would seem the high priest and chief priests are one and the same yet KJV mentions them simultaneously thereby rendering the whole text incomprehensible.

How can we understand the KJV translation  of Acts 5?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in Greek text in Acts 5:24 as follows:

**NA28/UBS5 etc:**

ὡς δὲ ἤκουσαν τοὺς λόγους τούτους ὅ τε στρατηγὸς τοῦ ἱεροῦ καὶ οἱ ἀρχιερεῖς, διηπόρουν περὶ αὐτῶν τί ἂν γένοιτο τοῦτο = Now when they heard these things, both the captain of the temple and the chief priests were perplexed concerning them, what this might be.

**TR/Byzantine text etc:**

Ὡς δὲ ἤκουσαν τοὺς λόγους τούτους ὅ τε **ἱερεὺς καὶ** ὁ στρατηγὸς τοῦ ἱεροῦ καὶ οἱ ἀρχιερεῖς, διηπόρουν περὶ αὐτῶν, τί ἂν γένοιτο τοῦτο = Now when they heard these things, both the **priest and** the captain of the temple and the chief priests were perplexed concerning them, what this might be.

Note the extra words of the latter from which the KJV was translated.

The addition is found in none of the early manuscripts and thus is omitted from UBS and NA28 and similar texts.  Why it was added later is unknown.  The addition appears odd because of the use of the marker, τε (both), which then introduces three items - one might normally expect  more such markers in a longer list but it is not impossible.

Comment: Most likely, scribes were confused by the proximity of "temple (ιερου)" and high (αρχ-) "priest (ιερεις)" in the same sentence, inasmuch as the presence of "chief" priest implies a simple "priest" whenver it is preceded by "and" and the aforementioned word which looks like priest (namely, the word for temple).

Comment: @SolaGratia - that theory appears very plausible.